# Performance concern in Recycler view while rendering various types of cell

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

In a recycler view there are mainly 3 types of cell. I have achieved that through the following piece of code

```
final int TYPE_COMMENT = 10004;
final int TYPE_UPDATE = 10005;
final int TYPE_ACTIVITY = 10006;
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if(activity.getActivity().getType().equalsIgnoreCase(CHECKIN_COMMENT_STRING)){
      return TYPE_COMMENT;
   }else if(activity.getActivity().getType().equalsIgnoreCase(CHECKIN_UPDATE_STRIND)){
      return  TYPE_UPDATE;
   }else if(activity.getActivity().getType().equalsIgnoreCase(CHECKIN_HISTORY_STRING)){
       return  TYPE_ACTIVITY;
   }
    return TYPE_ACTIVITY;
}
```

Then the issue came while i am inflating the second one.It have a complex layout with mainly 5 parts. Each cell have a chance to come with the one or combination of this 5 parts(having LinearLayout root and followed by some complex widgets). So i have done research and find we can overcome it by following ways.

1. By using visibility (View.GONE), I can hide/show the desired part.
2. Define each part in view stub and inflate it when required.
3. Programatically add widget to desired parts(But i am not recommend this since views are much complex)
4. Define separate cell for each combination of parts but it may take 5! cell design  thats 120 cells. So not possible

   Can you please suggest which is the better way to do (Or suggest alternative), while performance is my key constraint.

[image: Image of 2nd type of cell]

Comment: instead of playing on visibility, try multple ViewHolder?

Comment: Already using multiple viewholder in order to render main 3 types of cell. But further classification needed for 2nd type. Since its having 120 variations (described point 4 in question), its difficult create that much of view-holders... am i right?

Comment: it would be easy to manage multiple view holder instead managing visibility, your code would be more complex in the case of visibility.

Comment: can you post design which designer provide to you

Comment: added the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is the goal and the quantity of those complex layouts are not very high then I suggest you to don't recycle the complex views, that's to assign a different ViewType for each one and then to fill all values in onCreateViewHolder and not in onBindViewHolder. The scrolling will be smoother.

**A tip:**

I used this system in a complex list with layout containing many widgets, textviews, editboxes, seekbar and others it worked fine but sometimes unexpectedly onCreateViewHolder was called twice for the same ViewType, and that caused the data previuosly entered by the user to be lost. I solved it finally using a Map of already created ViewHolder vs viewType  `Map<Integer, MyViewHolder> holderMap = new HashMap<>();`
and in onCreateViewHolder I return the previuos holder if it exist.

Hope it will help

Comment: Can we render that complex layout parts using viewstub?... Is it overcome performance issue

Comment: The data of each cell will be different then how can fill data on onCreateViewHolder rather than onBindViewHolder ?.

Comment: Just fill data before onCreateViewHolder returns, No problem to have different data for different rows, you will have independent holder for each one, instead with only one holder the data will be filled each time you scroll in onBindViewHolder and this slows down a lot.

Comment: But I want to create 120 independent holder for that, is it  a good practices?

Comment: It should not be hard to try both versions, put data filling code in a method and call it from onCreateViewHolder or onBindViewHolder and also modify getItemViewType to return different view types in first case or the same  type for the second.

Comment: why you are ignoring 2nd point in my question. Is there any issue with viewStub?

Comment: I don't know about viewstub, never used it.

Comment: Your idea is of using different ViewTypes to handle complex item parts is genius.  Have some overly complicated Recycler items and was struggling on how to deal with the complexity and poor performance related view inflation, listeners and whatnot.  Was grouping views, adjusting visibilities and also explored ViewStub, but ViewType is such an elegant way to handle this.  Add some ListAdapter and not only do you get great performance, but “free” beautiful animations tool.  Also add some MutableLiveData and Views happily appear/disappear on the fly with little code.  Very grateful.